# strange for vim script in the for-in struct

Tags: vim

```
  5 function VaptGet(command_arg, package_arg, ...)
  6     let vapt_command = ''
  7     let command_list = ['install', 'remove']
  8     echo command_list
  9     for commands in command_list:
 10         if commands == a:command_arg:
 11             let vapt_command = commands
 12         endif
 13     endfor
 14     echo a:package_arg
 15     echo "hello world"
 16 endfunction
 17 command! -nargs=* VaptGet call VaptGet(<f-args>)
```

When I run:

```
:VaptGet install tab
```

I get:

```
['install', 'remove']
Error detected while processing function VaptGet:
line    4:
E121: Undefined variable: command_list:
E15: Invalid expression: command_list:
tab
hello world
```

Can somebody tell me why `command_list` is missing var

Answer (score 0):

Vim does not use colons in `for` loops and other constructs:

```
for commands in command_list
    if commands == a:command_arg
        let vapt_command = commands
    endif
endfor
```

Comment: yes, you are right, i mixed it with python, them are so similar, thank you very much, it's take long time to find out